# Parent:Flex vs Child:inline-block or inline (Benefit of using CSS3 flex?)

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I was trying to understand the usage of CSS3 new entry of display:"flex". What great benefits it has brougt along with it. However, I could not find any great benefit of this new property, except putting a virtual horizontal line (1 per flex box container) to have all the inside items. Wasn't this same achieved with inner items using display:inline or display:inline-block? What new magic has this property brought or what value does it bring in to CSS designign?

**Case 1:** (using flex in parent)

```html
<html>
<head>

<style>
div{background:blue;display:flex;}
p{background:yellow;}

</style>
</head>

<body> 
<div>
<p>This is para1.</p>
<p>This is para2.</p>
<p>This is para3.</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Case 2:** (Using display inline to childs)

```html
<html>
<head>

<style>
div{background:blue;}
p{background:yellow;display:inline;}

</style>
</head>

<body> 
<div>
<p>This is para1.</p>
<p>This is para2.</p>
<p>This is para3.</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Case 3:** (Using inline-block in childs)

```html
<html>
<head>

<style>
div{background:blue;}
p{background:yellow;display:inline-block;}

</style>
</head>

<body> 
<div>
<p>This is para1.</p>
<p>This is para2.</p>
<p>This is para3.</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please, help me out understanding the use-case of flex and what new can it achieve!

Comment: Read this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ to see what Flexbox can do.

Comment: @LGSon - very useful.

Comment: Also, this question is off-topic asking for which is better and when, as there is no _better_, and in your case, just 3 ways of doing similar things. Try be more specific to what you want to do.

Comment: If it could have been done earlier exactly same thing, no benefits of bringing new value to do the same. There must be a hidden door!

Comment: I like to use flex for the `order` propriety  [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Comment: For your sample, can be done with old tech, for many other things there is a new door .... the Guide link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This question is somewhat off-topic and very broad, I still decided to answer though, as I think it could have an initial value for users who are new to Flexbox*

Below is some samples, based on the questions code, that show some of the things Flexbox can do that standard block/inline-block/inline can't (some might with a lot of hacks/tricks).

To dig deeper, here is a good article: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

---

Properties for the flex container (has the `display: flex;`)

The `justify-content` property, defaults to `flex-start`

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;   /*  distribute the remaining space around each item  */
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is P1</p>
  <p>This is P2</p>
  <p>This is P3</p>
</div>
```

The `align-items` property, defaults to `stretch`

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;      /*  hor. center  */
  align-items: center;          /*  ver. center  */
  
  /*  gave a height so the vertical centering can be seen  */
  height: 150px;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is P1</p>
  <p>This is P2</p>
  <p>This is P3</p>
</div>
```

---

Properties for the flex items, the (*immediate*) children of the flex container

The `order` property, defaults to `0`

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;              /*  move 2nd item last  */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is P1</p>
  <p>This is P2</p>
  <p>This is P3</p>
</div>
```

The `flex-grow` property, defaults to `0`

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;           /*  make 2nd item fill the remaining space  */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is P1</p>
  <p>This is P2</p>
  <p>This is P3</p>
</div>
```

The `margin` property, defaults to `0`

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;        /*  push the 2nd/3rd item to the right  */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is P1</p>
  <p>This is P2</p>
  <p>This is P3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

*I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but here it goes -*

**`display: flex;`** is more advanced than **`display: inline;`** or **`display: inline-block;`** but it is only supported from **`IE11`** but other most of the browsers support it very well. `display: flex;` is much easy to manage once you learn them that's why the new **[Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)** is based on them.

If you want a good explanation of the advantages of all these display properties you better read **[this blog](http://blog.karenmenezes.com/2014/apr/13/floats-inline-block-or-display-table-or-flexbox/)**, this helped me very much when I started my study on them.

If you want to know the best way of implementing them and their tricks you better read **[this blog](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties)**, this also has a **playground demo** where you can check all the differents.

**This is the most common use of `display: flex;` -**

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

div.flex {
  display: flex;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 1%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is para1.This is para1.This is para1.</p>
  <p>This is para2.This is para2.</p>
  <p>This is para3.</p>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <p>This is para1.This is para1.This is para1.</p>
  <p>This is para2.This is para2.</p>
  <p>This is para3.</p>
</div>

<span>In here you can see than when i used the  <strong>display: flex;</strong></span> the height of the child is same irespetive of its content. Hope you got the point.
```